# How to specify float precision from variable in logging using % formatting?

Tags: python, logging

I want to avoid the eager evaluation of f-strings in logging, therefore I use %-formatting.

The precision is defined by a variable `precision`.

```py
import logging
value = 3.14159
logging.error("%.2f", value)

precision = 2

logging.error(f"{value:.{precision}f}") # OK but eager evaluation
logging.error("%.*f", value, precision) # fails
logging.error("%.%if", value, precision) # fails
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why is eager evaluation a proplem here? It would only be an issue if you saved the format string in a variable.

Comment: @Barmar: I assume they're engaged in premature optimization and trying to avoid the cost of formatting the string when the logging level isn't high enough to emit it. For `error` level, that's probably pointless (you're unlikely to omit error level messages), but for chatty debug messages, there might be a small benefit to avoiding creating the full string when 99% of uses outside of debugging would not use it. That said, I doubt it matters most of the time; f-strings have gotten *very* fast, and the other overhead involved in logging likely outweighs trivial savings from avoiding temp str.

Comment: @Barmar Not a problem here but following the practice of using lazy formatting for logging. I used `.error` so that one can copy-paste my minimal code and see the output directly (no need for extra line to change debug level).

Comment: @thomast: Nice of you to think of that. I'll note, in practice (just tested with an IPython microbenchmark after using `logging.basicConfig(filename='/dev/null')` to ensure the output didn't blow up my terminal), the incremental benefit of avoiding eager formatting is in fact pretty minimal (though apparently the eager printf-style approach still beats the f-string). I compared `logging.debug('%.*f', precision, value)` to `logging.debug('%.*f' % (precision, value))`, and the cost per call for lazy was 424 ns, vs. 682 ns for eager printf-style (849 ns for equivalent f-string).

Comment: True, that's 1.5-2x the cost for eager formatting here. But the baseline cost is already pretty high (so you wouldn't want to do this too much in a hot loop no matter what), and the eager code is still within an order of magnitude (so there are few cases where you'd accept the lazy overhead but not the eager). If the eager did nothing else for you, okay, maybe stick to lazy, but as I note in my answer, lazy evaluation can hide bugs that only bite you when you turn up the logging level to figure out a problem and discover debug level logging never worked in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
logging.error("%.*f", value, precision) # fails
```

is almost correct, but the precision has to come *first*:

```
logging.error("%.*f", precision, value) # works
```

Mnemonic: The placeholder `*` for precision comes before the placeholder `f` for the `float` value, so the precision is provided before the `float`.

---

Sadly, while the mnemonic applies in other formatting tools, it's applied to the *beginning* of each placeholder, not the end. For example, in `str.format`, the auto-numbering of placeholders is based on the order of the open brace `{` for each placeholder, so for that case, you'd do:

```
'{:.{}f}'.format(value, precision)
```

since the open brace for the placeholder for `value` comes before the open brace placeholder for precision. Of course, in that case, you can avoid ambiguity by being explicit and numbering them:

```
'{0:.{1}f}'.format(value, precision)
```

or naming them:

```
'{value:.{precision}f}'.format(precision=precision, value=value)  # Order of kwargs irrelevant
```

With f-strings of course, you inline the names being used in each place so no confusion exists:

```
f'{value:.{precision}f}'
```

and it's faster than any other means of string formatting in modern Python, so for any logs likely to actually get emitted in normal use, I'd just stick with the f-strings. Even for ones that *won't* get emitted, the overhead of logging stuff that's below the logging level (and doesn't get emitted) is high enough that the savings from avoiding the temporary `str` are pretty minimal in context, and the risk of a mistake that isn't noticed unless logging is turned up is high enough, that I'd typically use eager formatting, especially for more complicated cases like this. I've definitely been bitten by code of the form:

```
 logging.debug('%s %s', a, b, c)
```

where the code was executed unconditionally, but never with `DEBUG` level logging enabled; the first time I needed it to figure out a problem, the code broke due to the mismatched placeholder counts. A similar problem is impossible with eager formatting, whether it is modern f-strings or less modern `str.format` or even eager `printf`-style formatting like `logging.debug('%s %s' % (a, b, c))`; you'd see the error even if logging was turned off entirely.